# Stop Tkinter window taking focus when created

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, win32gui

I want the tkinter window i'm creating to stop taking the program focus when it is opened but still stay on top and 'lifted' the program is simple however I cant seem to find a solution to make the window open but not take focus as im not even sure thats possible.

```
from tkinter import *

Window = Tk()

champ_text = Label(Window, text='hello', font="arial, 100",)
champ_text.pack()

Window.wm_attributes('-disabled', False)
Window.lift()
Window.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)

#Window.overrideredirect(True)

Window.mainloop()
```

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do?
What does, "stop taking the program focus" mean?

Answer (score 0):

Foreground = focus. In my head.

You can however decide where you want the window to open on the screen:

```
Window.geometry('200x200+400+400')
```

"200x200" is the size of the window that you open.
"+400+400" is the placement on the screen for the window.

Open the window in the foreground on the side of the screen will make it not so much in focus?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).